# Sphinx option to download current page

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

In the top right of each documentation page, I would like an option for users to download the current file that they are currently viewing.

Are there any extensions or conf options that achieve this?

---

EDIT: as seen in JupyterBook

[image]

Comment: In every web browser, File > Save Page As..., or something similar.

Comment: @StevePiercy that pulls down all of the html like the sidebar. I just want the markdown page to download

Comment: Right-click on "View page source" and choose "Save Link As..."?

Comment: @mzjn yes, that works. just looking to get feature parity with jupyterbook as seen in edit to op.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax feature parity in this case is between *"Jupyter Notebook"* and whatever browser you are using. The way to implement this would be to include a link in the header and generate both single file HTML's and PDF making them available at the link. So it's possible out-of-the-box.